# How to insert blank values to mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql

I am working in an application where i have to insert blank values to mysql database using java.I am using "" as blank values but it is not inserting as blank values.How to do that

Comment: Where is your code and what is appearing after the insert?

Comment: If you are using a `PreparedStatement` you can use the [setNull(...) method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull(int,%20int))

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "blank value"? What happens when you use `""`, and how is that different from what you wanted? Please [edit] your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending "null" or null as the value while setting it from java.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your project, but you can use the default statement in the table description.

Ex :
    create table test (str varchar(32), ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

Or you can use "NULL" in your insert statement.